# Install app using JSOM in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, jsom

We have requirement that SharePoint hosted app need to add/remove in site when site creation(Site has been created using JSOM). I did't find any article regarding add app programmatically using JSOM.

My app is in **appcatalog**. I need to add it in site when site provisioning. usually we will do using UI [Site -> Site Content -> Add an app].

Is this possible in JSOM? or can i achieve this in any other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a custom app to a SharePoint Online site programmatically](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137894/how-to-add-a-custom-app-to-a-sharepoint-online-site-programmatically)

Comment: That post is for CSOM, the question for JSOM

Answer (score 1):

For now, there is no supported method/function in JSOM which can help you to install app programmatically. As per the comment of Swayam, you can use CSOM to deploy an app.

CSOM has a built in method **[Web.LoadAndInstallApp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.loadandinstallapp.aspx)** to install app.

Please refer to this link for more details:
[How to add a custom app to a SharePoint Online site programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137894/how-to-add-a-custom-app-to-a-sharepoint-online-site-programmatically) or  you can also refer to this link:
[Office 365: Publish and deploy .app through PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134408/office-365-publish-and-deploy-app-through-powershell)

Hope this will help you.