# AppPrincipals in SharePoint Online with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

An app that installs without issues manually via UI needs to be installed automatically. 
It's a provider-hosted app with Azure website.

The solution here: [Office 365: Publish and deploy .app through PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134408/office-365-publish-and-deploy-app-through-powershell) gives me ALMOST what I need - the app is installed on the site, but throws an error about permissions to the remote site:

> The remote event receiver callout failed. Details: Access denied. You
>   do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

The difference between successful manual sites and unsuccessful Powershell-deployed ones, seems to be within App Principals:
[image]

On the failed sites, the app principal for MyApp is missing.
How can I add it in SharePoint **Online** site using Powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question with a (disappointing) answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233878/set-spappprincipalpermission-equivalent-in-sharepoint-online).

So, in short, it is not possible at the moment.