# Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission equivalent in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is there an equivalent of the server cmdlet `Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission` in SharePoint Online?

I could do it with SharePoint Online Management Shell, PnP, CSOM, or honestly anything else (apart from manual UI).

I could not find anything in the Powershell modules, and `.LoadAndInstallApp($appIoStream)` does not seem to include that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not an equivalent of the server cmdlet Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission in SharePoint Online.

We can only set the permission of the app by SharePoint UI in SharePoint online. There is not csom / powershell code for doing such thing **on sharepoint online**

As a workaround, you can try to build some scrapper as the shown on this [post](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2019/06/grant-permissions-and-trust-sharepoint.html), which explains a script that simulates clickc on a browser